# Is it necessary to use the eventDestroy() callback?

Tags: javascript, dom, fullcalendar, javascript-objects, fullcalendar-4

Here's the scenario, let's say:

I attach a Tooltip to every event rendered as described here (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender). Is it necessary to use the eventDestroy() callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDestroy) to call the dispose() method on the Tooltips.

Would it be redundant to do this? Or would it be beneficial?

Comment: Why do you need to destroy anything? I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. What situation are you thinking of where you need to do that? And what problem do you envisage if you don't do it?

Comment: I don't know if I need to destroy anything, that's my question... sorry if it wasn't clear. I was thinking if I don't do it, the listeners for the Tooltips might build up over time as someone uses the calendar. On the flip side, I was thinking that if the listeners are tied to the elements, then calling the dispose function would be redundant, as they will get erased with the elements when the date range is changed.

Comment: I think the latter theory would be correct. If you had a tooltip attached to an event element it makes sense it would be deleted when the element is removed. Depends a bit how you created your tooltips, maybe and how that tooltip plugin works internally. I guess some detailed inspection using your Developer Tools might give you some clues. But frankly unless you have hundreds of events I wouldn't worry too much about things "building up", you're unlikely to run out of memory or anything

Comment: Lol yeah I don't think it would get that bad, I'm just nitpicking possible issues. Thanks for giving me your opinion, I will investigate and post the answer when I have it.